# Shared content does not display when sharing to Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, share

I implemented this piece of code to share some text to different apps and social networks:

```
btnShare.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
            String sharingText = "This is the text I want to share";

            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sharingText);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Share using"));
        }
    });
```

I works fine on all apps like gmail, twitter, evernote, message, etc. However, if I chose share using Facebook, it open the facebook app, but the content is blank.

Anyone has any idea on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

yes in order to share your data in facebook you have to use facebook API,
and in this link [Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/) you will find the offical documentation wich is very detailed

```
  public void postToWall(String message){
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("message", message);
            parameters.putString("description", "topic share");
            try {
                facebook.request("me");
        String response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
        Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
        if (response == null || response.equals("") ||
                response.equals("false")) {
            showToast("Blank response.");
        }
        else {
            showToast("File posted to your facebook wall!");
        }
        //finish();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        showToast("Failed to post to wall!");
        e.printStackTrace();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit about the code that you provided? I am not really understand it. Is that an external lib comes from Facebook? I saw something like facebook.request...

Comment: Hi there, sorry to getting back that later. I just been so busy last 2 weeks. Today I am continue working on this feature. Can you show me how to setup sdk using Android Studio? I have read the link you sent but it seems like only for Eclipse.